# check values of other columns if current column includes a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I want to check my first column and see if the string includes a particular substring or not. if yes, I want to obtain values from other columns. For example,

```
First      Second     Third
Jan,12        1          111
Feb,13        3          89
Jan,9        7          90
```

For each row where the word **Jan** comes, I want to extract the values of `Second`and `Third` for that row and append them to different lists. I tried this to obtain the values as a sample but it just gives me true or false.

```
print(df_performance['Jan' in df_performance['First']]['Second'].values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `contains` + `loc`

```
df.loc[df['First'].str.contains('Jan'),'Second']
Out[287]: 
0    1
2    7
Name: Second, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How can I do so for all the rows? Is it possible to get a sum of values obtained through this method? Or can we do it for more than one columns at once?

Comment: @a125 check `df.loc[df['First'].str.contains('Jan'),['Second','Third']].sum()
`

Comment: For most, I need a sum but for one case, I need an average. Is there any way to also count the number of rows coming into each category? For example, ```df.loc[df['month].str.contains('jan'),['check']].sum()))``` and if I know the number of rows where 'jan' comes, I can simply divide the final sum.

Comment: @a125 `df.loc[df['month].str.contains('jan'),['check']].value_counts()`

Comment: It says AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'